# how to keep update and keep track of two dimensional array in java?

Tags: java

I want to creat cinema menu , the only problem I have when I buy a ticket the result doesn't keep update, but it just show changes of current situation, in this problem I just stocked because I don't really know how to store information in the way that it won't distract all other things in my program , sorry for including .

```
public void seatsUI() {
            int number = Math.max(this.seats, this.rows);
            char[][] arr = new char[rows][seats];
            int[] filler = new int[number];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < seats; j++) {
                    //arr[i][j] = 'S';
                    if (i + 1 == this.buyTicketRow && j + 1 == this.buyTicketSeats) {
                        arr[i][j] = 'B';
                    } else {
                        arr[i][j] = 'S';
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Cinema:");
            System.out.print("  ");
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                filler[i] = i + 1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < seats; i++) {
                System.out.print(filler[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                System.out.print(filler[i] + " ");
                for (int j = 0; j < seats; j++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }

        public void rowToBuy(int row) {
            this.buyTicketRow = row;

        }

        public void seatsToBuy(int buyTicketSeats) {
            this.buyTicketSeats = buyTicketSeats;
        }
```

Comment: Please could you add your expected output vs the output you want to see?   That will help people better understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this and see if it solves your question.

```
public class Test
{

   private static final char PURCHASED = 'B';
   private static final char AVAILABLE = 'S';

   public int seats = 10;
   public int rows = 5;

   public char[][] purchaseSingleSeat(char[][] arr, int buyTicketRow, int buyTicketSeats) {
   
      final int max = Math.max(this.seats, this.rows);
      
      int[] filler = new int[max];
      
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < seats;  j++) {
            if (i + 1 == buyTicketRow && j + 1 == buyTicketSeats) {
               arr[i][j] = PURCHASED;
            } else {
               char oldValue = arr[i][j];
               arr[i][j] = oldValue == PURCHASED ? oldValue : AVAILABLE;
            }
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Cinema:");
      System.out.print("  ");
      for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
         filler[i] = i + 1;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < seats; i++) {
         System.out.print(filler[i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         System.out.print(filler[i] + " ");
         for (int j = 0; j < seats; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      
      return arr;
   
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      Test test = new Test();
      char[][] arr = new char[test.rows][test.seats];
      
      arr = test.purchaseSingleSeat(arr, 1, 1);
      arr = test.purchaseSingleSeat(arr, 2, 2);
      arr = test.purchaseSingleSeat(arr, 3, 3);
      arr = test.purchaseSingleSeat(arr, 4, 4);
      
   }
   
}
```

Here is the console output

```
Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 B S S S S S S S S S 
2 S S S S S S S S S S 
3 S S S S S S S S S S 
4 S S S S S S S S S S 
5 S S S S S S S S S S 
Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 B S S S S S S S S S 
2 S B S S S S S S S S 
3 S S S S S S S S S S 
4 S S S S S S S S S S 
5 S S S S S S S S S S 
Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 B S S S S S S S S S 
2 S B S S S S S S S S 
3 S S B S S S S S S S 
4 S S S S S S S S S S 
5 S S S S S S S S S S 
Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 B S S S S S S S S S 
2 S B S S S S S S S S 
3 S S B S S S S S S S 
4 S S S B S S S S S S 
5 S S S S S S S S S S
```

Comment: the problem is user input should be stored in ,but even I change to your example still , after second input it shows only second input result , for example 1,1 is become again "S" and only 2,2 become "B" , but I need store those infos:(

Comment: That is not true - my answer IS storing those inputs. I have added the output to my answer. Look at it again. Are you storing the result into `arr`? If not, then yes, you will overwrite the changes you made, but if you store into `arr`, then that is no longer true.

Comment: you were very true , I didn't store it in arr